# How to query for minimum should match in solr with edismax

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I am using Solr 4.10.2

How can I query in solr admin for "Minimum Should Match(mm)" with edismax selected. Can anyone please explain with an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link to understand concept of **mm** in solr: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/15/querying-more-fields-more-results-stop-wording-and-solrs-mm-min-should-match-argument/

- for ex; q= fox brown white & mm=2
  then it will gives result based on 2-matches. i.e, search result may be contains brown fox or black white fox..

`http://localhost:8983/solr/340Nop/select?q=pc+netbook&wt=json&indent=true&defType=dismax&mm=2`

I mean it gives result based on minimum stopwords.

I hope it will understandable & helpful.